# How to select multiple columns in the db?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I will Update more than one table in the PostgreSQL db. They all have similar names. 
For example:

1. `usa-al_nt_2016_q3_a_2-8-1b1`
2. `usa-ak_nt_2016_q3_a_2-8-1b1`
3. `usa-al_nt_2016_q3_a_2-8-1b1`

How can I Update all of these tables inside my db with this structure **usa-..._nt_2016_q3_a_2-8-1b1**?

Comment: One UPDATE per table. But the question is rather why you have several tables with similar names (and perhaps also contents)?

Answer (score 0):

You should create procedure which in loop invoke `execute` function with dynamic update.

```
for .... loop
    execute 'UPDATE ' || your_table || ' SET name = ' || your_name || ' WHERE id = ' || your_id;
end loop;
```

edit, show this:

```
declare
    rec record;
begin
for rec in (select table_name from information_schema.tables where position('usa-' in table_name) = 1 and table_name like '%_2016_q3_a_2-8-1b1') loop
    execute 'UPDATE ' || rec.table_name || ' SET name = ' || your_name || ' WHERE id = ' || your_id;
end loop;
```

Comment: ok but how can can I loop for example over tables with the beginning "usa-" and the end"_2016_q3_a_2-8-1b1"???

Comment: I get an error: [ERROR ] 29.0:syntax error, unexpected character. Do you know what this means?